# Why do I need to define a function in order to pass it to a template function that is not invoking it?

Tags: c++, templates, linker

The case is clearer than the question title.

I have this piece of code running OK. It declares a function and then prints its type:

```
int f(int);  // function receiving int
std::cout << "int f(int); type of f = " << typeid(f).name() << std::endl;
```

But when I pass the function as a parameter to a template function, the linker complains of it being undefined (LNK2019: undeclared external symbol `int __cdecl f(int)`):

```
template<typename T>
void PrintDeclarationAndType(std::string text, T var)
{
    std::cout << text << typeid(var).name() << std::endl;
}
int f(int);  // function receiving int
PrintDeclarationAndType("int f(int); type of f = ", f);
```

I don't understand why I have to define the function. Is it just because the linker is not clever enough to detect that the function is never invoked within the templated code? Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates generate code.  Your function template generates functions.  In this case, it generated:

```
template<>
void PrintDeclarationAndType(std::string text, int(*var)(int))
{
  std::cout << text << typeid(var).name() << std::endl;
}
```

there is a bit of magic in how the `T`s are deduced, but once this is generated this is "just a function".

We then look at how it is called:

```
int f(int);  // function receiving int
PrintDeclarationAndType("int f(int); type of f = ", f);
```

Through a C legacy feature, the function name `f` "decays" into a pointer to function:

```
int f(int);  // function receiving int
PrintDeclarationAndType("int f(int); type of f = ", &f);
```

now I hope you see the problem; you took a pointer to `f` and thus the pointed to function must exist.

Replace with

```
int f(int);  // function receiving int
&f;
```

and you still get a linker error.

`typeid` is not a function, it is a built-in operator.  So no pointer is formed, no linker error occurs.

Comment: Thanks. So it seems there are two key points here, a bit hidden. One is that `&f`. The other, and maybe more important, is the fact that `typeid` is a language operator and that `typeid(f).name()` is evaluated during compilation without needing a pointer to function. One of my doubts was to see if I could implement something similar to `typeid`, but receiving two parameters, using templates but I guess I can't. I could do that with a macro...

Comment: @rturr "Similar to" is vague.  Also, try asking that question in a new SO question, with yoyr actual requirements, and what you tried.  (If you provide too-strict requirements the answer is more likely to be no than if they are looser)

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a function pointer to another function: a template instance. That instance of a template function is, itself, a function, which is no different than any other non-template function, conceptually. So, with that in mind:

The fact that the template function doesn't invoke the pointed-to function is immaterial. You're passing a pointer to a function. The pointer has to point ***somewhere***. Whatever it's pointing to must exist. The fact that the pointer is not used to invoke the function makes no difference.

Just like if you had a function somewhere that takes, as a parameter, a pointer to a plain `int`, to call it with a pointer to some `int`, somewhere, that "`int` somewhere" has to exist. When you're taking an address of something, to produce a pointer, that "something" has to exist. The fact that the function you're calling will never use that pointer to read or update that `int` does not make any difference.

There are no workarounds. This is how C++ works. A linker is only "clever" enough to take a list of references to symbols from one set of translation units, the list of defined symbols in another set of translation units, and tie them together. It's very unlikely that a linker has a virtual machine, built-into it, to analyze every bit of code being linked in order to figure out whether a particular symbol will actually be executed, from somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. What happens then in the piece of code that is running OK? I assume that`typeid` is not a function and I'm not passing `typeid` a pointer to function.

Comment: Correct, typeid is evaluated at compile time. This is no different than passing a pointer to a function which does not actually use that pointer, but, say, takes its `sizeof`. It doesn't change the fact that the pointed-to object must exist. Theoretically, a compiler could determine that not generating the code to take the pointer of the object/function has no observable effect, and can be completely optimized away, but C++ does not require the compiler to do so, and if it still does it there's nothing that can be done about it.

Comment: But my template function is also evaluated at compile time. And `typeid` doesn't require the function to be defined.

Comment: No, your template function is not "evaluated at compile time". That's not how C++ works.

Comment: Ah OK, sorry, yes. Its code is generated at compile time but then the evaluation just happens at execution time.